# zsh: command not found: softwareupdate

Tags: apple-m1, software-update, rosetta

I am trying to run below command on m1 chip mac which throws error: **zsh: command not found: softwareupdate**

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

softwareupdate is a function you are trying to call with the zsh shell, the error is telling you it cant find that function... looks like you are trying to install rosetta...

Try this? https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/11/17/installing-rosetta-2-on-apple-silicon-macs/

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```